# passing variables on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

just having some issues with this jQuery thing.

What i'm trying to do is:

i have some audio control buttons that look like this:

```
<p><a href='#' onClick="player1.loadAudio(1); return false;">Play audio</a></p>
```

but there are too many on the page so i'm trying to optimise the code and make a little function that checks for the div id on the button and adds tells the player what track to play.

so i've done this:

```
 <div id="audioControlButtons-1">
     <div class="speaker">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="play">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="pause">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[id^=audioControlButtons-] div.play").click(function() { 
          var id =    new Number;
          id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace(/audioControlButtons-/, ''); 
          //alert(id);
          player1.loadAudio(id);
          return false;
        });
      });

</script>
```

my problem is:

the id is not passing to the the player1.loadAudio(**id**)

if i hardcode  player1.loadAudio(**1**)

it works! but the moment i try to pass the variable to the function it doesn't work...

however if you uncomment the **alert(id)** thing you will see the id is getting generated...

can someone help?

cheers,
dan

Comment: Are you sure it's not getting something? Put an alert(id) in player1.loadAudio and see if you aren't getting something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem. The variable id is a string. Try;

```
player1.loadAudio(parseInt(id));
```

Yah and the initialise line isn't necessary. Just use;

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace(/audioControlButtons-/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually kind of confused with your example because you originally have this:

```
<p><a href='#' onClick="player1.loadAudio(1); return false;">Play audio</a></p>
```

but then you don't reference it again.  Do you mean that this html:

```
<div id="audioControlButtons-1">
    <div class="speaker">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="play">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pause">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Is what you are actually creating?  If so, then you can rewrite it like this:

```
<div class="audio-player">
    <div class="speaker">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="play" data-track="1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="pause">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Then in your script block:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".audio-player > .play").click(function() { 
            var track = $(this).data('track');
            player1.loadAudio(+track);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

So a few things are going on here.

1. I just gave your containing `div` a class (`.audio-player`) so that it's much more generic and faster to parse.  You don't want to do stuff like `[id^=audioControlButtons-]` because it is much slower for the javascript to traverse and parse the DOM like that.  And if you are going to have multiples of the same element on the page, a class is much more suited for that over IDs.
2. I added the track number you want to the `play` button as a `data` attribute (`data-track`).  Using a `data` attribute allows you to store arbitrary data on DOM elements you're interested on (ie. `.play` button here).  Then this way, you don't need to this weird DOM traversal with a `replace` method just to get the track number.  This saves on reducing unnecessary JS processing and DOM traversing.
3. With this in mind now, I use `jQuery`'s `.data()` method on the current DOM element with `"track"` as the argument.  This will then get the `data-track` attribute value.
4. With the new track number, I pass that along into your `player1.loadAudio` method with a `+` sign in front.  This is a little javascript trick that allows you to convert your value into an actual number if that is what the method requires.

There are at least a couple of other optimizations you can do here - event delegation, not doing everything inside the `ready` event - but that is beyond the scope of this question.   Hell, even my implementation could be a little bit optimized, but again, that would require a little bit more in depth explanation.